Minting gas cost is too high - ERC1155
I'm testing a Dapp that issues soulbound course certificates using ERC1155 tokens. I deploy the contracts normally in Sepolia, I created a course normally using the smart contracts. However, when I try to mint a certificate gas prices are insanely high (8 ETH) and this error shows up in Metamask: We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail.
I'll show the code. I'm using web3.js on the server side. This is the code I use to generate a minting request. Here, the authorized signer generates a signature used later to mint the certificate:
async generateMintingRequest(studentAddress, courseId) {
    await this.init();
    try {
        const nonce = await this.certificateMinterContract.methods.nonces(studentAddress).call();
        const messageHash = this.web3.utils.keccak256(
            ['address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'],
            [studentAddress, courseId, this.chainId, nonce]
        );
        
        // Sign the hash directly without the Ethereum prefix
        const signature = await this.web3.eth.sign(messageHash, this.account);
        
        return {
            studentAddress,
            courseId,
            nonce,
            signature
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to generate minting request:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

Then a student calls this function to launch the minting process:
async mintCertificate(studentAddress, courseId, signature) {
    await this.init();
    try {

        const nonce = await this.certificateMinterContract.methods.nonces(studentAddress).call();          
        // Call the mint function on the CertificateMinter contract
        const result = await this.certificateMinterContract.methods.mint(
            studentAddress,
            courseId,
            nonce,
            signature
        ).send({ from: this.account });

        console.log('Certificate minted successfully:', result);
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to mint certificate:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

The smart contract is divided in two. Firts one is the minter and has the mint() method. And the second one is used to manage the courses and certifications.
CertificateMinter.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Nonces.sol";
import "./CourseCertification.sol"; // Make sure this path is correct

contract CertificateMinter is Ownable, Nonces {
    using MessageHashUtils for bytes32;
    using ECDSA for bytes32;

    /* ============ Events ============ */
    event SignerChanged(address indexed oldSigner, address indexed newSigner);
    event CertificateMinted(address indexed to, uint256 indexed courseId);

    /* ============ State Variables ============ */
    address public signer;
    CourseCertification public courseCertification;
    uint256 public immutable _cachedChainId;

    /* ============ Constructor ============ */
    constructor(address courseCertificationAddr, address signer_) Ownable(msg.sender) {
        courseCertification = CourseCertification(courseCertificationAddr);
        signer = signer_;
        _cachedChainId = block.chainid;
    }

    /* ============ Public Functions ============ */
    function mint(
        address to,
        uint256 courseId,
        uint256 nonce,
        bytes memory signature
    ) external {
        require(courseCertification.balanceOf(to, courseId) == 0, "Certificate already minted");
        require(_useNonce(to) == nonce, "Invalid nonce");

        bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(to, courseId, _cachedChainId, nonce)
        );
        bytes32 ethSignedMessageHash = messageHash.toEthSignedMessageHash();
        require(signer == ethSignedMessageHash.recover(signature), "Invalid signature");

        courseCertification.issueCertificate(to, courseId);
        emit CertificateMinted(to, courseId);
    }

    function recover(address oldOwner, address newOwner, uint256 courseId) external onlyOwner {
        courseCertification.recover(courseId, oldOwner, newOwner);
    }

    function setSigner(address newSigner) external onlyOwner {
        address oldSigner = signer;
        signer = newSigner;
        emit SignerChanged(oldSigner, newSigner);
    }
}

CourseCertification.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract CourseCertification is ERC1155Supply, Ownable, Pausable {
uint256 private _courseIdCounter;

struct Course {
    string name;
    string description;
    string trainerName;
    uint256 startDate;
    uint256 endDate;
    uint256 durationInHours;
    bool active;
}

mapping(uint256 => Course) public courses;
mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => bool)) private _soulboundTokens;
mapping(address => bool) public minters;

string public name;
string public symbol;
string private _baseURI;

event CourseCreated(
    uint256 indexed courseId,
    string courseName,
    string trainerName,
    uint256 startDate,
    uint256 endDate,
    uint256 durationInHours
);
event CertificateIssued(uint256 indexed courseId, address indexed student);
event CourseUpdated(
    uint256 indexed courseId,
    string courseName,
    string trainerName,
    uint256 startDate,
    uint256 endDate,
    uint256 durationInHours,
    bool active
);
event CertificateRecovered(uint256 indexed courseId, address indexed from, address indexed to);
event MinterAdded(address indexed minter);
event MinterRemoved(address indexed minter);

modifier onlyMinter() {
    require(minters[_msgSender()] || owner() == _msgSender(), "Not authorized to mint");
    _;
}

constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_, string memory baseURI_) 
    ERC1155(baseURI_) 
    Ownable(msg.sender)
{
    name = name_;
    symbol = symbol_;
    _baseURI = baseURI_;
}

function setBaseURI(string memory newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
    _baseURI = newBaseURI;
}

function uri(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return string(abi.encodePacked(_baseURI, Strings.toString(tokenId)));
}

function createCourse(
    string memory courseName,
    string memory description,
    string memory trainerName,
    uint256 startDate,
    uint256 endDate,
    uint256 durationInHours
) public onlyOwner {
    uint256 newCourseId = _courseIdCounter;
    _courseIdCounter += 1;
    
    courses[newCourseId] = Course(
        courseName,
        description,
        trainerName,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        durationInHours,
        true
    );
    
    emit CourseCreated(newCourseId, courseName, trainerName, startDate, endDate, durationInHours);
}

function updateCourse(
    uint256 courseId,
    string memory courseName,
    string memory description,
    string memory trainerName,
    uint256 startDate,
    uint256 endDate,
    uint256 durationInHours,
    bool active
) public onlyOwner {
    require(courseId < _courseIdCounter, "Invalid course ID");
    
    Course storage course = courses[courseId];
    course.name = courseName;
    course.description = description;
    course.trainerName = trainerName;
    course.startDate = startDate;
    course.endDate = endDate;
    course.durationInHours = durationInHours;
    course.active = active;

    emit CourseUpdated(courseId, courseName, trainerName, startDate, endDate, durationInHours, active);
}

function getCourseDetails(uint256 courseId) public view returns (Course memory) {
    require(courseId < _courseIdCounter, "Invalid course ID");
    return courses[courseId];
}

function issueCertificate(address student, uint256 courseId) public onlyMinter {
    require(courses[courseId].active, "Course is not active");
    require(!_soulboundTokens[courseId][student], "Certificate already issued");

    _mint(student, courseId, 1, "");
    _soulboundTokens[courseId][student] = true;

    emit CertificateIssued(courseId, student);
}

function recover(uint256 courseId, address from, address to) public {
    require(_soulboundTokens[courseId][from], "No certificate to recover");
    require(from == _msgSender() || owner() == _msgSender(), "Not authorized");

    _soulboundTokens[courseId][from] = false;
    _soulboundTokens[courseId][to] = true;

    _safeTransferFrom(from, to, courseId, 1, "");

    emit CertificateRecovered(courseId, from, to);
}

function addMinter(address minter) public onlyOwner {
    minters[minter] = true;
    emit MinterAdded(minter);
}

function removeMinter(address minter) public onlyOwner {
    minters[minter] = false;
    emit MinterRemoved(minter);
}

function pause() public onlyOwner {
    _pause();
}

function unpause() public onlyOwner {
    _unpause();
}

function _update(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256[] memory ids,
    uint256[] memory values
) internal virtual override whenNotPaused {
    super._update(from, to, ids, values);

    if (from != address(0) && to != address(0)) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            uint256 id = ids[i];
            require(values[i] == 1, "Can only transfer 1 certificate at a time");
            require(_soulboundTokens[id][from], "Token is soulbound");
            _soulboundTokens[id][from] = false;
            _soulboundTokens[id][to] = true;
        }
    }
}

function safeTransferFrom(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 id,
    uint256 amount,
    bytes memory data
) public virtual override {
    super.safeTransferFrom(from, to, id, amount, data);
}

function safeBatchTransferFrom(
    address /*from*/,
    address /*to*/,
    uint256[] memory /*ids*/,
    uint256[] memory /*amounts*/,
    bytes memory /*data*/
) public virtual override {
    revert("Batch transfers are not supported for soulbound tokens");
}
}

I've been looking for an answer or a solution for hours, but nothing seems to come up. Thank you!
